# How do I transmute a base64 string into an input buffer?

Tags: node.js, base64, buffer

I'm trying to downsample an image in node. I have that image stored as a base64 encoded string (ie: "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR" etc.). I'm using Sharp npm package. The documentation appears to delineate that sharp can take either the filepath to an image or an "inputBuffer." I did some googling and assume the Buffer class is what they are referring to. Trying the code below among others continuously has resulted in me receiving the following error: "Input buffer contains unsupported image format." What could my issue be, and if you're not sure could you please recommend me a different npm package with more clear documentation?

```
 const downsizeProfileImgForTweet = (user, cb) => {
        let imgBuffer =  Buffer.from(user.profileImg, 'base64');
        sharp(imgBuffer)
        .resize(52, 52)
        .toBuffer()
        .then(data => {
            console.log("success");
            user.profileImg = data;
            cb()
        } )
        .catch( err => console.log(`downisze issue ${err}`) );
    }
```

I looked all over the internet and did a bunch of guess and checks, so forgive me for the noob question. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Did you remember to first strip off the non-base64 header data (the `'data:image/png;base64,'` part) before passing to `Buffer.from()`?

Comment: I did not will try that out now

Comment: @mscdex yes now it works!  thank you

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that the metadata (`'data:image/png;base64,'`) in the data URI is not being stripped off before being passed to `Buffer.from()`, causing the image data to be corrupt. Removing the metadata first should allow the data to be decoded properly, assuming the base64 content itself is valid.